# I could not createsuperuser for django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I want to create super user. 
 I used the command prompt to create super user.

When I write this code

```
Python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ysr\Desktop\Blog\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ysr\Desktop\Blog\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ysr\Desktop\Blog\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\ysr\Desktop\Blog\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\ysr\Desktop\Blog\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\ysr\Desktop\Blog\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 112, in handle
    username = self.get_input_data(self.username_field, input_msg, default_username)
  File "C:\Users\ysr\Desktop\Blog\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 193, in get_input_data
    raw_value = input(message)
  File "C:\Users\ysr\Desktop\Blog\venv\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0131' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am using pycharm2018.3.1x64

Please help me.

Comment: It seems like you accidentally put `u0131` character somewhere in code, please search for it, and when you remove it, everything would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "UnicodeEncodeError". Please try the character encoding 'utf-8' in your database field definition and related code parts.

Comment: I solved the problem with your answer thanks alot  both of you 

Comment: I want to thank everyone who answered .problem solved .you are great  

Answer (score 0):

if u need to write some text on other languages (not English I mean) in your documents.
this thing at top of your file can help u.
even if your text is commented

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```